# How do I select a specific element that has no text, but other contents inside, with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I have the following structure dynamically added to the body:

```
<ul>

 <li>
   <h5>Option 1 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
</li>

<li>
  <h5>Option 2 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
</li>

<li>
  <h5><img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
</li>

<li>
  <h5>Option 4 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
</li>

</ul>
```

As you can see, they are all the same, except for the fact that sometimes one of them will not have a title, but still have the img, which is the same for all of them. Is there any way I can select only the third li of the example above with Jquery so I can add a generic text on it when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `contents()` to check if the first child of the `h5` element is a textNode. If it's not, then you can `prepend()` whatever value you require. Try this:

```js
var $h5 = $('li h5');
$h5.filter(function() {
  return $(this).contents()[0].nodeType != 3;
}).prepend(function() {
  return 'Option ' + ($h5.index(this) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h5>Option 1 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5>Option 2 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5><img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5>Option 4 <img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5><img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5><img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h5><img src="..." alt="..."></h5>
  </li>
</ul>
```